# 「回答を投稿」と「破棄」がずれている

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

[image: 回答を投稿と破棄]

1. ベースラインが合っていないようにみえます
2. 「回答を投稿」ボタンと「破棄」の間がもう少し空いている方が見やすいです

Google Chrome 37.0.2062.94 / Mac OS X 10.9.5 / Retina

Comment: 現在はどうでしょうか？とりあえずベースラインは問題ないように感じました。

Comment: 回答いたしました通り解決しているようですので一旦、完了とします。

Answer (score 1):

デザイン変更に伴なって解決しているようです。

> [image: スクリーンショット]